# mysql vs sqlserver vs postgres Do they store indexes differently?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

I am currently benchmarking the three DBs for a special use case.

tabledata (10,000,000 rows)

```
id, facebook[random int 0-1,000,000], youtube[random int 0-1,000,000]
1, 322342, 293492
2, ...
```

6 queries:

```
SELECT youtube, facebook FROM file_results WHERE youtube > 500000 AND facebook > 500000 ORDER BY youtube DESC LIMIT 100
SELECT youtube, facebook, youtube+facebook as total FROM file_results WHERE facebook+youtube > 1000000 ORDER BY youtube DESC LIMIT 100
SELECT youtube, facebook, youtube+facebook as total FROM file_results WHERE facebook > 500000 AND youtube > 500000 ORDER BY facebook+youtube DESC LIMIT 100
SELECT youtube, facebook, youtube+facebook as total FROM file_results WHERE facebook > 900000 AND youtube > 900000 ORDER BY facebook+youtube DESC LIMIT 100
SELECT youtube, facebook, youtube+facebook as total FROM file_results WHERE facebook+youtube > 1000000 ORDER BY facebook+youtube DESC LIMIT 100
SELECT youtube, facebook, youtube+facebook as total FROM file_results WHERE facebook+youtube > 1800000 ORDER BY facebook+youtube DESC LIMIT 100
```

6 results (ms):

[image]

As you can see, mysql is very fast when returning data that part of existing indexes (facebook and youtube are both indexed). However the db timing rankings reverse when more complex queries are used that order by something that is not directly indexed (e.g. the sum of two columns). I think I recall that some DBs store the data directly in the indexes while other use a pointer to the actual data. Might this be the case

Comment: This could be different depending on what is currently in memory & what the machines are doing

Comment: I do not know about mysql and postgres, but in sql-server you need covered indexes and not the indexes on each column

Comment: databases have varying optimization techniques, one method will not work for all.

Comment: And what are your indexes???

Comment: @sepupic all columns have a single-column index. There are no composite indexes. (on purpose)

Comment: So there is no covering index at all? And your queries return almost the whole table and not only some rows? Congratulations: SQL Server did not use your indexes at all. (By the way you could see this in execution plan)

Comment: IOW: you cannot run a race with blind horses and blind jockeys. Well: you *could*, but the result wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @sepupic it does not return everything. There is a limit of 100 in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Each dbms has a different query optimizer. The query optimizer decides when and how best to use indexes.

Of these three--MySQL, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL--MySQL has the least sophisticated query optimizer. If you base your selection on queries that don't represent real-world queries, you'll probably not be happy with the results. See, for example, [Order By optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) for MySQL.

Query performance not just a question of whether the dbms can read a value from an index without fetching from the table itself. It's also a question of what kinds of indexes the dbms supports, how the database is deployed on disk, and how the dbms server is tuned, among other things. See, for example, [Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html) and [Tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

For the last queries, simply create an expression/function index on (facebook+youtube) which will greatly speed things up. Postgresql can do this easily, just use:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON table(facebook+youtube)
```

I bleieve MySQL can do this too, search for "Virtual Columns and Effective Functional Indexes" in the docs, as for SQL Server, I don't know, but considering its reputation, I would expect it does...

You could also use covering indexes like:

```
(youtube,facebook)
(facebook,youtube)
```

and variants including the facebook+youtube sum, but you will end up with lots of indexes slowing down the inserts and using tons of space, so it's a compromise.

However, I suppose the results of your "top 100" queries don't change every 2 seconds, so even if they're a bit slow, you can use a cron to make the queries every 5 minutes and cache the results, so you can have your results quickly while not using too many indexes for quick inserts...